# Multiple iterations of window.open() in async function

Tags: javascript

So, I'm working on a simple bot to send a message to several Whatsapp contacts. I inject the code below in the Whatsapp Web page, and it works perfectly for one single message. Then, when I use  sendMessageToPhoneList to send it to an array of phone numbers, it works fine for the first message/iteration but the next one give me this error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of null.

```
function sendMessage(phone, encodedMessage) {

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        var wppURL, wppPage;

        wppURL = "https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+phone+"&text="+encodedMessage;
        wppPage = window.open(wppURL);

        var send = function() {

            var sendButton = wppPage.document.getElementsByClassName("_3M-N-")[0];

            if (sendButton) {
                sendButton.click();

                setTimeout(function() {
                    wppPage.close();    
                    resolve(true);

                }, 10000);

            } else {
                setTimeout(send, 1000);
            }
        };

        send();
    });
}

async function sendMessageToPhoneList(phoneList, encodedMessage) {
    for (i=0; i < phoneList.length; i++) {
        await sendMessage(phoneList[i], encodedMessage);
    }
}
```

There's something wrong with the code? Can someone please give me some insight? Thanks!

Comment: try using `let wppURL, wppPage;` instead of `var wppURL, wppPage;`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is chrome will open same tab again, so even though you are opening window multiple windows with same name and chome does not allow it change your code so that you have different window name and it should fix it.

For, example:

```
wppURL = "https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+phone+"&text="+encodedMessage;
wppPage = window.open(wppURL, wppURL); // second parameter is for window name
```